# How to sort strings in a structure lexicographically?

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, structure

I'm trying to sort strings according to their names lexicographically.

so I have an array of structures

```
typedef struct buff{
    char *name;
} structure;
```

and I'm copying names of files with their associated extensions. So that the content of that structure looks like `s[0].name = "picture1.jpg"` `s[1].name = "DCP003.JPG"` and stuff like that.

and I'm trying to sort that, and I'm unable to achieve that.. what I have so far is this.

```
void sort(structure *s, int counter){

    for (int i = 0; i < counter - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < counter - 1 - i; j++){

                if (strcmp(s[j].name, s[j+1].name) > 0){

                    structure tmp;

                    tmp = s[j];
                    s[j] = s[j+1];
                    s[j+1] = tmp;

            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%d - %s\n", i+1, s[i].name);
    }
}
```

and it doesn't work as I want.. tried several versions still no good .. where am I making mistake? Any advice is greatly appreciated..

Comment: `s[0].name = "picture1.jpg";` is **not** copying.

Comment: use a radix sort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271367/radix-sort-implemented-in-c

Comment: @Mahesh I know how to copy content of a string into another one .. actually I'm using sprintf for this one, this was just to illustrate what content there may be.

Comment: You realize you're not using a good algorithm, right? That library routines exist to do it faster? That being said, please post some sample input and output so that we can see what you mean by "does not work"

Comment: @Arkadiy you mean "bubble sort" isn't a good algorithm? it worked, I was just doing something wrong, when I rewrote it, everything worked just fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
typedef struct buff{
    char *name;
} structure;

structure s[5];

void sort(){
    int sz = sizeof s / sizeof s[0];
    printf("sz=%d\n",sz);
    int done = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
          for (int j = i+1; j < sz; j++){

                  if (strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) > 0){

                      structure tmp;

                      tmp = s[i];
                      s[i] = s[j];
                      s[j] = tmp;
              }
          }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
        printf("%d - %s\n", i+1, s[i].name);
    }
}

int main() {
  s[0].name = "dog";
  s[1].name = "ant";
  s[2].name = "cat";
  s[3].name = "man";
  s[4].name = "bear";
  sort();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
---------- Capture Output ----------
> "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c c:\temp\temp.exe
sz=5
1 - ant
2 - bear
3 - cat
4 - dog
5 - man

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```

Comment: while I was testing your solution I found that with slight modification mine was working as well .. so thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to sort strings in a structure lexicographically order is using QSort (Stdlib.h)(O(nlog(n))).

This is the Sample Code::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct names
{
    char strvalues[20];
} buff[100];


int main ()
{
    int i;
    strcpy(buff[0].strvalues,"some");
    strcpy(buff[1].strvalues,"example");
    strcpy(buff[2].strvalues,"strings");
    strcpy(buff[3].strvalues,"here");

    qsort (buff, 4, 20, (int(*)(const void*,const void*)) strcmp);


    for(i=0;i<4;++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n",buff[i].strvalues);    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really never knew how to use it properly, anyhow we were supposed to write that algorithm ourselves, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ Markus :: I wrote the above code as it is fast (Onlog(n)) run time complexity.But your code follows the selection sort algorithm   O(n^2),which is quite slow.So the fastest and easiest way to sort string is qsort . Try to go through the tutorial of stl http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/ ,it will help you to understand well :)

Comment: for the purpose of my homework I just needed to sort them out no matter the speed, but thank you for expanding my knowledge :)