# Which sorting algorithm should be used that runs in O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out which algorithms are the best to use for certain specifications.

Here's the prompt:

> ***Write an algorithm to sort n integers, each in the range
>   [0..((n^4)-1)] in O(n) time.***

I'm more of a visual learner and understand best with examples. I made up values for this to visualize it, but I don't know what sorting method to use or how to figure out which to use. Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Bubble sort and insertion sort do not run in O(n) (except in special cases)

Comment: Read up on Radix sort. You can do a trick with your choice of basis. That is the only way, as far as I know, to do this by the way.

Answer (score 9):

Like I said in my comment, the only way to do this, as far as I know, is [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). You basically sort the numbers by comparing each digit separately.

The full complexity of the algorithm is **O(d(n + b))**, where **b** is the basis chosen and **d** is the number of digits in that basis. You can choose any basis pretty much, and work with the numbers in that basis.

The trick here is to choose the right basis. There exists a basis that would make the algorithm **O(n)**, but if you just use base 2, each number would have up to **O(4 logn)** digits and so the total complexity would be **O(n logn)**.

As a hint, there exists a basis in which each number in the range would have a constant number of digits.

Comment: What's the basis then?

Comment: I'm not going to say it explicitly, since this seems to be a homework question. There is pretty much only one way to choose a basis in which the numbers in the range would have a constant number of digits. It's kind of tricky, like I said.

Comment: Well, you don't mean base `n`, right? Because that's really a cheat unless you then count operations on that as costing O(log n), but that puts you back in the same situation as using a constant base

Comment: @harold I suspect that operations are meant to cost O(1).  With your interpretation you would not be able to even read your input data in O(n) so the problem is clearly impossible.  Base n isn't the only choice though, sqrt(n) would work just as well for example, but doesn't avoid your criticism.

Comment: Yes, the modern convention for random access machines is that you get unit-cost operations on machine words (which have at least log bits).

Answer (score 3):

Radix sort is the only sorting algorithm I know of that can run in linear time.

Here is a link that should be helpful - [Radix Sort implemented in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271367/radix-sort-implemented-in-c)

Comment: Thanks.How do I determine the radix value to use?

Comment: If you look closer, you realize that Radix Sort is O(nlog_10(n)).

Answer (score -5):

As far as I know there are no sort algorithms that run in O(n), Bubble sort runs in O(n^2). Quick sort runs in O(n log n)