# I am stuck at implementing Radix sort recursively

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion, radix-sort

I'm required to implement a programm that sorts numbers ranging from 0 to 99999 recursively (this is basically Radix sort). The process itself is kinda simpel: The user types in an array that contains those numbers in the main method. Then, the main method calls for the sort-method where I create a two-dimensional array named 'space' with 10 rows and 1 column. Then, I divide every number in the array by the digit, which would be 10.000 in the first run. So, for example, 23456 / 10000 = 2,3456 = 2 (in java), hence, the programm puts this number in space[2][0], so in the second row. Then, we take this entire row and extend it, which is done in the putInBucket-method. We do this in order to make sure that we can put another number into the same row.

We do this for every number that is inside the 'numbers'-array. Then, we want to work with these rows and sort them again by the same principle, but now we take a look at the second digit. We want to do this from left to right, not from right to left. So, if our second row would look like this

[23456, 24567],

we'd want to compare the 3 and the 4, which leads to 23456 < 24567.

We do this with the help of the recursive call at the end of the sort method. Now, this is where I am lost. I simply don't know how to manipulate the digit-variable in order to be able to work with the second, third, ... digit of each number. In the first run, as you see, this can be simply done by dividing through 10.000, but I didn't find a way to go further from here.

**Please note:** Yes, this is a homework question, hence, I'm only allowed to use primitives here. We didn't go through stuff like math.pow(...) yet. Thanks in advance!

```
public static int[] sort(int[] numbers, int digit) {

  if (numbers.length == 0)
    return numbers;

  int[][]space = new int[10][1];
  int i, j = 0;

  for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    i = numbers[j] / digit;
    space[i][0] = numbers[j];
    space[i] = putInBucket(space[i], numbers[j]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < space[i].length; i++) {
    sort(space[i], digit); //not sure how to work with digit here
  }

  return ... //not sure what to return here

}

private static int[] putInBucket(int[] bucket, int number) {

  int[] bucket_new = new int[bucket.length+1];

  for (int i = 1; i < bucket_new.length; i++) {
    bucket_new[i] = bucket[i-1];
  }

  return bucket_new;

}

public static void main (String [] argv) {

  int[] numbers = IO.readInts("Numbers: ");
  int digit = 10000;
  int[] bucket = sort(numbers, digit); 

}
```

Comment: As a first step, use your IDE to auto-format this code so it has consistent indentation (consistent indentation makes it much easier for you and us to see the structure of the code). As a matter of fact, I'd recommend configuring your ide to auto-format the code whenever you save the file.

Comment: I'm working with vim, there is no auto-format, I think.

Comment: What's wrong with the indentation here though?

Comment: Almost everything. For example, all the lines start at the same column as the method that they're part of. So we can't see that they're part of this method, where the method ends, etc. If you can't indent automatically using vim, then indent manually, or use an editor that you can indent with. Basically all code-centric editors allow doing that.

Comment: Even to a beginning programmer, I heartily recommend a professional Java IDE such as eclipse or netbeans (both open source), to benefit from  syntax highlighting, code completion, a built-in debugger, and various other cool features.

Comment: Give me a second, I will fix it. :-)

Comment: Better? That's basically the structure I tutors want us to use.

Comment: Much, thanks. Though I still recommend an IDE :-)

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: Personally, I use eclipse, though others prefer IntelliJ (the community edition is free) or netbeans. Any of these will do nicely for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the last digit, the remainder operator `%` is your friend:

```
123 % 10 == 3
```

if you haven't covered the `%` operator yet, you can use

```
123 % 10 == 123 - (123 / 10 * 10) == 3
```

To extract another digit, you can first move it to the end with `/`:

```
123 / 10 == 12
12 % 10 == 2
```

You can therefore extract an arbitrary digit using

```
(number / mask) % 10
```

where mask ∈ {..., 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1}.

**Extra credit**

Radix sort is usually implemented in the binary number system instead because a binary digit (or a sequence thereof) can be extracted without performing a division, which is more efficient:

```
x % 16 == x & 15;
x \ 16 == x >> 4;
```

Also, if you are implementing this for real, you'd need a more efficient way to grow buckets (your implementation takes O(n) to add a single element to the bucket, adding n elements to the bucket therefore takes O(n^2), which makes your radix sort slower than insertion sort). [Dynamic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) are usually implemented with a more efficient [geometric expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost).

Comment: And yes, we covered the modulo-operator.

Comment: The radix sort I know uses the [least significant digit first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Least_significant_digit_radix_sorts).

Comment: Not the recursive one, which can be found below in your article.

Comment: Ah ok, didn't know that variant. Ok, then extract the most significant digit first. In either case, you can extract the digit with `(number \ mask) % 10` where mask ∈ {..., 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1}.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Shouldn't be too hard to implement this - I hope. :-)

Comment: Done. Also gave some more pointers on how to improve your implementation for production use.

Comment: @meriton - for production use, the radix sort would be iterative and left to right (least significant first), and only needs a single instance of a working array. Right to left consumes a lot of space, or requires dynamic resizing, which consumes time.

Comment: @rcgldr: How do you make do with a single array? In particular, how do you represent the various buckets in that shared array while keeping each sorting step stable?

Comment: @meriton - Take a look at [example radix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271367/radix-sort-implemented-in-c/40457313#40457313) . This is a lsd (least significant digit) radix sort using 256 (one byte) as the "digit". A matrix of counts is generated, then converted into indices into the "output" array. The code alternates the move direction on each pass by swapping pointers. Since it's an even number of passes, the sorted data ends up in the original array. The example returns a pointer to the sorted array, but that's not needed as the sorted data ends up in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] numbers, int digit) {

     if (numbers.length == 0 || digit <= 0)
           return numbers;

     int[][]space = new int[10][10];
     int[] len = new int[10];
     int i, j = 0;

      for (j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
            i = (numbers[j] / digit) % 10;
            len[i]++;
            for (int k = len[i] - 1; k > 0; k--) {
                space[i][k] = space[i][k - 1];
            }
            space[i][0] = numbers[j];
      }


      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          int[] bucket = new int[len[i]];
          for (int k = 0; k < len[i]; k++) 
              bucket[k] = space[i][k];
          space[i] = sort(bucket, digit / 10); 
      }

      int k = 0;

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < len[i]; j++) {
              numbers[k] = space[i][j];
              k++;
          }
      }

      return numbers; 

}
```

a) Firstly, `space` is allocated as having only one column. So, `space[i] = bucket` will not work.

Instead, you could declare it as int[10][10]. (Note: it will only support max of 10 values in one bucket). Or you may allocate new arrays programmatically. Or of course, a `List` might be better suited.

b) `i = (numbers[j] / digit) % 10;`

To get the required digit only. For eg: if the number is `12130`, and `digit` = `1000`, we want to set `i` to `2`, not `12`.

c) `putInBucket` replaced with an in-place loop.

d) For each `bucket` of `space`, we sort it by one digit lower by calling `sort` recursively.

e) Finally, the result to be returned (`numbers`), can be created by looping through `space` from digit 0 to 9.

Note: 
This solution could probably be made better.

Comment: I'm not allowed to replace the putInBucket-method, sorry.

Comment: If that's the case, simply replace the loop with `space[i] = putInBucket(space[i])`. Also, why are you passing `numbers[j]` if you are not using it? I suspect you are supposed to set `bucket_new[0] = number` in `putInBucket` if that's the method signature you have been given.

Comment: I am using the numbers. They are copied at the end of the extended array, and then the whole thing is returned. If you start with 12345 and call the putInBucket-method with the first row and this number, then you'd get a new array that looks like this: [0, 12345]. Then, if another number with a leading 1 appears, for example 13456, then we are able to put it in the first position, so we'd get [13456, 12345] and extending it gives again: [0, 13456, 12345]. This is then meant to be sorted further.

Comment: I understand that. But please look at the `putInBucket` method you have posted. The variable `number` isn't used in the method body at all! That is what I'm saying. You might be looking to do `bucket_new[0] = number` in `putInBucket` instead of `space[i][0] = numbers[j]` in the `sort` method but forgot about it.

Comment: I was told that I need to work with the number-parameter because of the visibility, although I don't use it cleary. You might want to look into my updated version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323554/implementing-radix-sort-recursively-how-to-print-the-elements-at-the-end/41326917#41326917