# C++ RadixSort efficient ways

Tags: c++, sorting, radix-sort

I am trying to implement the [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) algorithm in C++ trying to sort an `int` array.
As far as I see, there are two possible ways:

1. Sort by binary digits, e.g. get bit after bit using bitwise operators and sorting  them in 2 buckets (0 and 1).
2. Sort by decimal digits, which makes 10 buckets (0 to 9).

I don't see which of the two would be more efficient however. Sorting in only 2 buckets seems to be quite inefficient, but using decimal digits means the fast bitwise operators can't be used and instead I have to use the especially slow `%` and `/` operators.

So which one of these would be faster?
(PS: the code I'm developing will be used in a very time-critical section that's why I ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one sorts into a power-of-2 number of buckets, so that one can reduce the number of passes AND benefit from bitwise operations.

Comment: So attempt 1 would make more sense? because I dont see how to increase the number of buckets to e.g. 4 or 8 if im using bitwise operators.

Comment: Or do you mean sorting e.g. by hex digits which would make 16 buckets?

Comment: Not by "hex digits" necessarily, but by a group of binary digits, yes.

Comment: [example base 256 radix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271367/radix-sort-implemented-in-c/40457313#40457313)